# PHP Encryption and C# Decryption [Rijndael]

Tags: c#, php, encryption, cryptography, rsa

I use RJ256 to login, since the return string is fairly small, it works (PHP gives encrypted string and C# needs to decrypt).

The data gets decrypted and fully works. Although, now I am transferring a 79KB string from PHP (Encrypted) to C# (Needs to Decrypt) and I get this error:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2286.png
This error only happens when the string is a bit larger than normally.

Here is my PHP code to encrypt:

```
private function _encrypt($data)
{
    $iv = "sfhfskfsusfdsfd79fd8s79sdf789f79";
    $key = "da4b9237bacccdf1";
    // to append string with trailing characters as for PKCS7 padding scheme
    $block = mcrypt_get_block_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
    $padding = $block - (strlen($data) % $block);
    $data .= str_repeat(chr($padding), $padding);

    $crypttext = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);

    // this is not needed here            
    //$crypttext = urlencode($crypttext);

    return base64_encode($crypttext);
}
```

Here is my C# Code to decrypt:

```
public static dynamic DecryptRJ256(string cypher, bool isJson = true, bool getBytes = false)
{
    string sRet;

    var encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
    var key = encoding.GetBytes("da4b9237bacccdf1");
    var iv = encoding.GetBytes("sfhfskfsusfdsfd79fd8s79sdf789f79");

    using (var rj = new RijndaelManaged())
    {
        try
        {
            rj.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            rj.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            rj.KeySize = 256;
            rj.BlockSize = 256;
            rj.Key = key;
            rj.IV = iv;
            var ms = new MemoryStream(Decode(cypher));

            using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, rj.CreateDecryptor(key, iv), CryptoStreamMode.Read))
            {
                using (var sr = new StreamReader(cs))
                {
                    sRet = sr.ReadLine();
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            rj.Clear();
        }
    }

    // ReSharper disable once AssignNullToNotNullAttribute
    return (isJson ? JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(sRet) : (getBytes ? Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sRet) : (dynamic)sRet));
}
```

How can I make it work?

Comment: Interesting, Rijndael with 256-bit blocks – any rationale behind the choice? It's not very portable outsize PHP and C#. Also, I hope you didn't just share your secret key with the world.

Comment: Which conversion is correct for your case `var key1 = encoding.GetBytes("da4b9237bacccdf1");
    var key2 = SoapHexBinary.Parse("da4b9237bacccdf1").Value;
    /*(namespace System.Runtime.Remoting.Metadata.W3cXsd2001)*/        `

Comment: try doing a cs.FlushFinalBlock(); before the closing brace for cs  = new CryptoStream.. block of code.

Comment: @ntoskrnl I don't get what your are saying. first one returns 16 bytes( 128 bit) and the second one 8 bytes. And i don't think the first one is correct.

Comment: @L.B Yeah, I just saw that too, comment deleted. Hex is ruled out for sure since AES doesn't work with 64-bit keys. I don't know what C# does when told to use a 256-bit key but given a 128-bit key.

Comment: @ntoskrnl I am not sure about the second but one the first is surely incorrect. What is the meaning of converting every char to byte and loosing(not using) the most significant bits (all ascii chars is 7 bits).

Comment: @L.B Doesn't quite work...

Comment: @raja It throws an error that it was already called

Comment: I retried with RJ_128 and the same error is being outputted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
  public static byte[] DecryptRJ256(string prm_key, string prm_iv, string prm_text_to_decrypt)
  {
        var sEncryptedString = prm_text_to_decrypt;

        var myRijndael = new RijndaelManaged();
        myRijndael.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
        myRijndael.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        myRijndael.KeySize = 256;
        myRijndael.BlockSize = 256;

        byte[] key;
        byte[] IV;

        key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(prm_key);
        IV = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(prm_iv);

        var decryptor = myRijndael.CreateDecryptor(key, IV);

        var sEncrypted = Convert.FromBase64String(sEncryptedString);
        var fromEncrypt = new byte[sEncrypted.Length];

        var msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(sEncrypted);
        var csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read);

        csDecrypt.Read(fromEncrypt, 0, fromEncrypt.Length);

        //Return (System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(fromEncrypt))
        return fromEncrypt;

  }
```